# Android Drag and Drop ACTION_DRAG_ENDED not firing

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I'm really having a time figuring this one out and can't find any friends with the relevant experience so far.  It's my VERY LAST FEATURE before I release my VERY FIRST APP so it's driving me crazy to have gotten bogged down with it with the end in sight!

My drag and drop works perfectly if I drop the object in an acceptable area.  However, if dropped somewhere else I do not get an event and cannot clean up after the failed drag drop operation.  I need the ACTION_DRAG_ENDED event to fire.  However this only fires (according to the documentation) if I respond to ACTION_DRAG_STARTED with a value of true (meaning it can accept the object).  The problem is ACTION_DRAG_STARTED is not firing!

So I believe the crux of the matter is that I'm not getting ACTION_DRAG_STARTED.  I'm putting what should be all of the relevant dragdrop code (or at least nearly all) here:

```
private OnTouchListener onTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            Item current = (Item) ((View) v.getTag()).getTag();
            //ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("test", "testText");
            View dragView = (View) v.getTag();
            DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new ItemDragShadowBuilder(dragView, 
                                new Point(v.getWidth()/2, v.getHeight()/2));
            dragSource = dragView;
            v.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, current, 0);
            dragView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }       
    }

};

private static class ItemDragShadowBuilder extends View.DragShadowBuilder {

    private Point touchPoint = null;
    private Point sizePoint = null;
    private View dragView = null;

    public ItemDragShadowBuilder(View dragView, Point touchPoint) {
        super();
        sizePoint = new Point(dragView.getWidth(), dragView.getHeight());
        this.touchPoint = touchPoint;
        this.dragView = dragView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onProvideShadowMetrics (Point size, Point touch) {
        size.set(sizePoint.x, sizePoint.y);
        touch.set(touchPoint.x,touchPoint.y);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawShadow(Canvas canvas) {

        dragView.setBackgroundColor(dragView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.holoBlueDark));
        dragView.draw(canvas);

        //canvas.setBitmap(dragView.getDrawingCache());
        //canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        //dragView.setAlpha(1);

        //How do I change the transparency?
        //super.onDrawShadow(canvas);
    }



}


private View dragSource = null;

private OnDragListener onDragEventListener = new OnDragListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        final int action = event.getAction();

        switch (action) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), ((EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edtParent)).getText().toString() + " started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT/8).show();
            return true;
            //break;//DRAG AND DROP>>>START DOESN"T FIRE
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            if ((dragSource != null) && (dragSource != v)) {
                Item source = (Item) dragSource.getTag();
                Item target = (Item) v.getTag();
                int sourcePos = source.getPosition();
                int targetPos = target.getPosition();
                if (targetPos < sourcePos)
                    source.moveUp(sourcePos - targetPos);
                else
                    source.moveDown(targetPos - sourcePos);
                dragSource.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                dragSource = null;
                fireOnChecklistNeedsResetListener();
                return true;
            }
//              View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
//              Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), ((EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edtParent)).getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT/8).show();
//              Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), ((EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edtParent)).getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT/8).show();
            // Dropped, reassign View to ViewGroup
//              View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
//              ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
//              owner.removeView(view);
//              LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) v;
//              container.addView(view);
//              view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
            dragSource.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            dragSource = null;
            fireOnChecklistNeedsResetListener();
            if (!event.getResult())
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "UNHANDLED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT/8).show();

//              View vieww = (View) event.getLocalState();
//              Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), ((EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edtParent)).getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT/8).show();
//              Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), ((EditText) vieww.findViewById(R.id.edtParent)).getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT/8).show();
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:

            v.setBackgroundColor(v.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.holoBlueLight));
            return true;
            //break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:        
            v.setBackgroundColor(v.getContext().getResources().getColor(android.R.color.background_light));
            return false;
            //break;
        default:
            break;
    }
        return false;
    }

};
```

Extended information:  The dragView is an item layout in a listview (specifically an expandablelistview).  The view that accepts the touch event is a small glyph on the view with a small grip.  Here is a screenshot with a drag operation in progress (took some fancy finger work to get this lol):

[image: Drag/Drop Screen]

So if I were to drop the dragged item on another item (this reorders them) it works great.  If I drop it somewhere else no event fires so I can never clean it up.  So for example in the upper part of the screen or if the list is short in a blank area or the blue bar on bottom or any of the system areas.

I could alternatively solve this problem by figuring out a way to prevent dragging away from a valid area so if you know how to do that, that's another way to solve it.  My last option would be to implement an event for every possible view on the screen (again these are list view layouts, on a listview, which is on a fragment, which could be on various activities) so obviously this would not be desirable.  And in fact if I do that I still may have a problem if it's dropped in a system UI area (like systembar or capacitive buttons area) but I'm not sure.

In case it is helpful here is where I assign the relevant event procedures (I removed irrelevant lines) in the list view adapters get view item method:

```
public View getGroupEdit(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView != null) {
                //irrelevant stuff omitted
    } else
        convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.edit_group_item, null);
    Item group = (Item) getGroup(groupPosition);
    convertView.setTag(group);
    EditText edtParent = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edtParent);
    edtParent.setTag(convertView);
    scatterItemText(edtParent);

            //irrelevant stuff omitted

    ImageView imgGrip = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgGrip);
    imgGrip.setTag(convertView);
             //irrelevant stuff omitted     

            imgGrip.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener);
    convertView.setOnDragListener(onDragEventListener);
    return convertView;
}
```

And finally FWIW, this is the layout XML for the list item view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="55dip"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/imgGrip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/dark_grip2"
    android:contentDescription="@string/strReorder"/>
<CheckBox 
    android:id="@+id/chkParent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgGrip"
    android:checked="false"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtParent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/chkParent"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnInsert"
    android:textSize="17dip" 
    android:inputType="text"
    android:hint="@string/strItem"/>
<ImageButton
    android:id="@id/btnInsert"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/viewParent"
    android:src="@drawable/dark_content_new"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:hint="@string/strAddItemAbove"
    android:contentDescription="@string/strAddItemAbove" />   
<View 
    android:id="@id/viewParent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnExpand"/>    
<ImageButton 
    android:id="@id/btnExpand"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/dark_add_sub_item"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:hint="@string/strViewSubItems"
    android:contentDescription="@string/strViewSubItems"/>   
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: Please delete that picture that is unrelated to the question

Comment: Are you adding your listener to the "non relevant" areas? Looking through your code real quick I didn't see it but I might have missed something

Comment: Oh you party poopers!  Sorry for those who missed the pony.  Thanks Bali for your pony appreciation.  JRaymond, well that's what I'm trying to avoid and according to the documentation that should not be necessary.  If I can get a start event then I'll get an end and can check the result there if negative.

Comment: I won't repost the pony but for posterity here is a link: http://i.stack.imgur.com/0IhoQ.gif

Comment: @GeeksOnHugs Where in the documentation have you read that that shouldn't be necessary? If you don't add your eventlistener to the other viewGroups then they won't listen for events, be they start or end

Comment: I can find it for you if you like let me know but as I recall it was in the dragon drop guide on developer.android.com. Essentially what is saying is that I would know that the drag drop a vent is ending because I would get an action drag and event fired off in on drag. That would give me enough information to know when to clean up the UI and I wouldn't have to bother Hooking up all of the other views which might be a hassle because this is on a fragment that might be on several screens.

Comment: I guess it didn't say it explicitly. I'll look it up and posted back here could you put your idea in a response (official answer) so we have more room to discuss?  edit: sorry for the typos I'm doing this on mobile with voice to text. Be back on my PC momentarily.

Comment: Well, I guess I'll try that...if nothing fires though if dropped in system UI areas then I'll have to give up on drag and drop for now till I solve this. :-(

Comment: Be sure to address me with an @ or I won't catch your comments :) e.g. @JRaymond. Writing up an answer now

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Views that need to be notified of drag events must register `OnDragListeners`.  If they need to be aware when specific things or types of things move, for instance in order to change their appearance (either to a "DRAG ME HERE!" or a "DON'T YOU DARE DROP THAT ON ME!").  Even if your view is not a valid place to drop the object being dragged, if it needs to be  'drag context aware' so to speak, it registers an `OnDragListener` and returns true for`ACTION_DRAG_STARTED`.

The one thing I'm missing from your very thorough question is what exactly you need to be cleaned up?  If you just need to do some generic things that are in the scope of the activity, you might consider adding a different `OnDragListener` to the base `RelativeLayout` that registers for the events but waits for `ACTION_DRAG_ENDED` to alert the activity to perform your generic cleanup code

Comment: Thanks, what you said, I'm sure would take care of it, and I accepted the answer.  I'm going to edit your post with an addendum for what I ultimately did in my situation.  BTW, the clean up referred to a view I made invisible and any drag over background color changes.

Comment: I added an addendum to your answer but I came back and don't see it.  I guess someone has to approve it?  @JRaymond maybe you have to allow it or something?

Comment: Some other reviewers rejected it because "This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post." It might be more correct to edit your own post, though I admit I'm not 100% familiar with the guidelines for this kind of thing

Comment: That's effed up.  I put how I got it to work.  I wanted to post that here to make this a more valuable resource for the next person who comes along, it wasn't for my benefit.  That's not right.  Well for a future reader with this problem, the short answer is when a view assigned an onTouch listener is different than the view assigned the onDrag listener I did not get a start/stop.  When I made them the same I got a start/stop to fire.  My touch view was an icon on the larger drag view.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation here. it solved my problem. To make the right answer more noticeable, you should edit your original question to include the explanation.  @GeeksOnHugs

Answer (score 2):

This may be related to this issue:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25073

Overriding the dispatchDragEvent function as suggested at that link worked for me:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchDragEvent(DragEvent ev){
    boolean r = super.dispatchDragEvent(ev);
    if (r && (ev.getAction() == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED
            || ev.getAction() == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED)){
        // If we got a start or end and the return value is true, our
        // onDragEvent wasn't called by ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent
        // So we do it here.
        onDragEvent(ev);
    }
    return r;
}
```