# OnDragListener not receiving DRAG_STARTED or DRAG_ENDED, but does get ACTION_DROP

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I'm running into a weird problem with an `OnDragListener`. My target view gets the `ACTION_DROP` event fine and handles it; but it never receives the `ACTION_DRAG_STARTED` or `ACTION_DRAG_ENDED` events (in fact it never receives any events besides drop).

What could be causing this? It's an issue because I can't handle the case when the drop happens outside of the target.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184511/android-drag-and-drop-action-drag-ended-not-firing) but the answer was not clear to me. Any ideas greatly appreciated.

My draggable view has this `OnTouchListener`:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev) {
  switch (ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
      startPointX = ev.getX();
      startPointY = ev.getY();
      isOnClick = true;
      break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
      if (isOnClick) {
        isOnClick = false;
        // handle single click
      }
      break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
      if (isOnClick && movePassesThreshold(ev)) {
        isOnClick = false;
        draggableView.startDrag(...);
      }
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  return true;
}
```

And the target view has this `OnDragListener`:

```
@Override
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
  switch (event.getAction()) {
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
      Log.v(TAG, "drag started");
      break;
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
      break;
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
      break;
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
      Log.v(TAG, "drop");
      // handle drop
      break;
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
      Log.v(TAG, "drag ended");
      break;
    default:
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: You are not calling the startDrag() method in your OnTouch of your draggable view. The commented part of the code where you want the dragging to start have you tried calling the startDrag() ?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I just commented that part out for the purpose of posting here. But I am calling draggableView.startDrag(...), which gets started correctly and the drop gets handled by the target. It's just that the start and end events don't fire. (edited post to be clear)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution is this workaround: when my `OnTouchListener` gets ACTION_UP, set a 1-second delayed runnable to check if the view is still dragging. If the `OnDragListener` received the drop, the runnable does nothing; but if it didn't the runnable calls stop drag to clean up and reset the view to its previous position.

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
  if (isOnClick) {
    isOnClick = false;
    // handle single click
  } else if (draggableView.isDragging()) {
    uiHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        if (draggableView.isDragging()) {
          // Drop never got received, so call stopDrag
          draggableView.stopDrag();
        }
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
  break;
```

Answer (score 6):

This is a known issue with the ViewGroup:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25073

Overriding the dispatchDragEvent function as suggested at that link worked for me:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchDragEvent(DragEvent ev){
    boolean r = super.dispatchDragEvent(ev);
    if (r && (ev.getAction() == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED
            || ev.getAction() == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED)){
        // If we got a start or end and the return value is true, our
        // onDragEvent wasn't called by ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent
        // So we do it here.
        onDragEvent(ev);
    }
    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i am doing it. I dont know if it will work for you or not but still posting.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
         final ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("position",position + "");
         v.startDrag(data, pieceDragShadowBuilder, v, 0);
         return true;
}
```

then in my Listener its :

```
                @Override
                public boolean onDrag(View pV, DragEvent pEvent) {
                  final int dragAction = pEvent.getAction();

                  View dragView = (View) pEvent.getLocalState();
                  final FrameLayout container = (FrameLayout) pV;

                            if (dragAction == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED)
                            {

                            } 
                            else if (dragAction == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED)
                            {

                            }
                            else if (dragAction == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED) 
                            {

                            } 
                            else if (dragAction == DragEvent.ACTION_DROP) 
                            {

                            }
```

Now the only difference i see from your code is that i am calling the `startDrag()` method in my `onTouch()` regardless of the specific events of MOVE or UP or CANCEL.