# OnDragListener not receiving callbacks after dragged fastly

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, touch, drag

Firstly, this question may looks like duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410949/ondraglistener-not-receiving-drag-started-or-drag-ended-but-does-get-action-dro), and looks like recorded as issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25073), but after looking into the details, you will realize that it is completely different.

#### The setup

I am trying to implement a simple drag and drop function: When I drag ImageView A to ImageView B, they will swap their background color.

[image: Effect Illustration]

You can download this little test project [here](https://github.com/siralam/DragSwapImageTest). The problem described below can be reproduced by cloning it and build it on your phone.

Look at [MainActivity](https://github.com/siralam/DragSwapImageTest/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/asksira/dragswapimagedemo/MainActivity.java) if you just want to look at the code.

#### The problem

If you perform the drag and drop slowly (e.g. 0.5 seconds for each drag and drop), it works perfectly.

However, if you try to drag and drop at your fasted speed (e.g. 4 to 5 times in a second, anyway your fastest speed), soon you will find that the drag and drop action cannot be performed anymore. By looking at the log, I find that **none of the drag callbacks are fired**.

```
03-12 10:41:53.782 (...) I/dragEvent: view.startDragAndDrop has been called
03-12 10:41:53.787 (...) I/dragEvent: ACTION_DRAG_STARTED received
03-12 10:41:53.787 (...) I/dragEvent: ACTION_DRAG_STARTED received
03-12 10:41:53.789 (...) I/dragEvent: ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED received
03-12 10:41:53.789 (...) I/dragEvent: ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION received
03-12 10:41:53.796 (...) I/dragEvent: ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION received
03-12 10:41:53.802 (...) I/dragEvent: ACTION_DROP received
03-12 10:41:53.815 (...) I/dragEvent: ACTION_DRAG_ENDED received
03-12 10:41:53.815 (...) I/dragEvent: ACTION_DRAG_ENDED received
03-12 10:41:54.014 (...) I/dragEvent: view.startDragAndDrop has been called //Since this call, no callbacks were received
```

At this point, the app does not freeze. OnTouchListener is still receiving callbacks.
The drag and drop freezes because I have a flag to indicate whether the drag and drop is in progress, and since ACTION_DRAG_ENDED is not fired, this flag is stuck at `true` and therefore no more drag and drop action can be performed.

I have really no idea why, since I have logged everything, every lines of code are running correctly and I expected to receive callbacks from Android framework, but it is not...

#### Why I think it should be solvable

Actually, this little test project is me trying to clone the drag and drop image swap implemented in [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mt.mtxx.mtxx) app. And I cannot reproduce this problem in their app... So I think there must be something wrong in my code; or some alternative to tackle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fast drags are resulting in flings that you are not processing and the drag and drop facility is not informing you that it is not proceeding by officially ending the drag. The following updated `MainActivity.java` has the following changes:

1. A lot of the code that dealt with things that were not drag related was removed. I just did this to simplify the posting here and for no other reason.
2. Introduction of `GestureDetectorCompat` to detect when a fling is happening. I don't do anything with this, just log that it happened. You may want to consider the gesture detector facility for touches in your code.
3. Checked for an `ACTION_UP` event to reset the layout if the drag was not completed (`isDragging == true`).

It seems that flings have a messy ending when a drag has been started. The code below can help you resolve your issue.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView ivGrid1, ivGrid2, ivGrid3, ivGrid4;
    private GestureDetectorCompat mDetector;

    //Drag and Drop
    View dragOriginView;
    Drawable whiteDrawable;
    Drawable tempDrawableStorage;
    boolean isDragging = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new MyGestureListener());

        ivGrid1 = findViewById(R.id.grid_1);
        ivGrid2 = findViewById(R.id.grid_2);
        ivGrid3 = findViewById(R.id.grid_3);
        ivGrid4 = findViewById(R.id.grid_4);

        setupTouchListeners();
        setupDragListeners();

        whiteDrawable = new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.white));
    }

    private void setupTouchListeners() {
        View.OnTouchListener listener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int action = event.getActionMasked();

                switch (action) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        return true;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        boolean beyondLeft = event.getX() <= 0;
                        boolean beyondRight = event.getX() >= v.getWidth();
                        boolean beyondTop = event.getY() <= 0;
                        boolean beyondBottom = event.getY() >= v.getHeight();
                        if (beyondLeft || beyondRight || beyondTop || beyondBottom) {
                            startDragAndDrop(v);
                            return true;
                        }
                        isDragging = false;
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        if (isDragging) {
                            dragOriginView.setBackground(tempDrawableStorage);
                            tempDrawableStorage = null;
                            v.setAlpha(1.0f);
                            isDragging = false;
                        }
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
        ivGrid1.setOnTouchListener(listener);
        ivGrid2.setOnTouchListener(listener);
        ivGrid3.setOnTouchListener(listener);
        ivGrid4.setOnTouchListener(listener);
    }

    private void startDragAndDrop(View view) {
        if (isDragging) return;
        isDragging = true;
        dragOriginView = view;
        view.setAlpha(0.5f);
        ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((String) view.getTag());
        ClipData dragData = new ClipData((String) view.getTag(), new String[]{ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN},
                                         item);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            view.startDragAndDrop(dragData, new View.DragShadowBuilder(view), null, 0);
        } else {
            view.startDrag(dragData, new View.DragShadowBuilder(view), null, 0);
        }
        Log.i("dragEvent", "view.startDragAndDrop has been called");
        tempDrawableStorage = view.getBackground();
        view.setBackground(whiteDrawable);
    }

    private void setupDragListeners() {
        View.OnDragListener listener = new View.OnDragListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
                Log.i("dragEvent", "<<<<<<<<<<<<<<called");
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                        Log.i("dragEvent", "ACTION_DRAG_STARTED received");
                        return event.getClipDescription().hasMimeType(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN);
                    case ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                        Log.i("dragEvent", "ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED received");
                        v.setAlpha(0.5f);
                        return true;
                    case ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
                        Log.i("dragEvent", "ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION received");
                        return true;
                    case ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                        Log.i("dragEvent", "ACTION_DRAG_EXITED received");
                        v.setAlpha(1f);
                        return true;
                    case ACTION_DROP:
                        Log.i("dragEvent", "ACTION_DROP received");
                        v.setAlpha(1f);
                        swapColor(v);
                        return true;
                    case ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                        Log.i("dragEvent", "ACTION_DRAG_ENDED received");
                        if (!event.getResult() && v == dragOriginView) {
                            dragOriginView.setBackground(tempDrawableStorage);
                            tempDrawableStorage = null;
                        }
                        v.setAlpha(1f);
                        isDragging = false;
                    default:
                        //Do nothing
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
        ivGrid1.setOnDragListener(listener);
        ivGrid2.setOnDragListener(listener);
        ivGrid3.setOnDragListener(listener);
        ivGrid4.setOnDragListener(listener);
    }

    private void swapColor(View dragTarget) {
        if (dragOriginView == dragTarget) {
            //Restore color
            dragOriginView.setBackground(tempDrawableStorage);
            tempDrawableStorage = null;
            return;
        }
        Drawable targetBackground = dragTarget.getBackground();
        dragOriginView.setBackground(targetBackground);
        dragTarget.setBackground(tempDrawableStorage);
        tempDrawableStorage = null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        this.mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    class MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "Gestures";

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) {
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onDown: " + event.toString());
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2,
                               float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onFling: " + ((event1 != null) ? event1.toString() : "" + event2.toString()));
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: //resulting in flings that you are not processing and the drag and drop facility is not informing you that it is not proceeding by officially ending the drag// <- This is the true answer by looking at the log!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Check out below snippet

```
private void setupTouchListeners () {
    View.OnTouchListener listener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                return true;
            }
            if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                boolean beyondLeft = event.getX() <= 0;
                boolean beyondRight = event.getX() >= v.getWidth();
                boolean beyondTop = event.getY() <= 0;
                boolean beyondBottom = event.getY() >= v.getHeight();
                if (beyondLeft || beyondRight || beyondTop || beyondBottom) {
                    startDragAndDrop(v);
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // done changes here, simply changed flag to false and return false
                    isDragging=false;
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
    ivGrid1.setOnTouchListener(listener);
    ivGrid2.setOnTouchListener(listener);
    ivGrid3.setOnTouchListener(listener);
    ivGrid4.setOnTouchListener(listener);
}
```

How ever its having logical issue of color which is not part of this question by doing above changes you will be able to drag at what ever speed you would like.

Happy coding :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! With the above change, which basically *reactivate* the drag and drop, prevents the drag and drop from freezing. However the root problem of not receiving callbacks still exist. I would upvote your answer since it did helped; but I would not accept it yet; see if any answers can address the "not receiving callbacks" issue. Thanks again!